# "chrome.runtime.reload is not a function" when trying to livereload my extension runtime

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I am building a chrome extension, and have integrated it with `livereload-js`. It is working, except that the call to `chrome.runtime.reload()` throws an error that the function `reload` doesn't exist on the `chrome.runtime`. This is weird, since the documentation says that this method should be there and when I read the [the docs for the reload method](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-reload) it says that this method should be available without any additional permissions needed. If this was removed in Manifest version 3, it hasn't been explained in the docs.

To simplify I have removed most of the code from the app, and am simply trying to get the livereload to work. Here is my `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "name": "Cool AF",
    "description": "something cool",
    "version": "1.1",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://nevermind/*"],
            "css": ["main.css"],
            "js": ["main.js", "livereload.js"]
        }
    ],
    "host_permissions": ["http://localhost:35729/"],
    "permissions": ["storage", "management", "activeTab", "alarms", "background"]
}
```

The code in `livereload.js` considers if it is a chrome extension and calls `chrome.runtime.reload()`, which throws an error. I have removed all other code from the extension besides a `console.log` that let's me know the extension is loading. Any ideas on how to get the `reload` function to appear on the `chrome.runtime` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chrome.runtime.reload` isn't available for content scripts.

See [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/) for the list of methods available to content scripts; *some* `chrome.runtime` methods are, but not all:

> `runtime`:
>
> - `connect`
> - `getManifest`
> - `getURL`
> - `id`
> - `onConnect`
> - `onMessage`
> - `sendMessage`

The idiomatic way is to [message](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/) your background script to request it to perform an operation content scripts aren't allowed to do.

Comment: Exactly what I was missing. Thank you for pointing this limitation in content_scripts. It makes sense, too, why the Chrome team did this.